# Logstash Grok doesn't change @timestamp

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying Grok with the following filter

```
  grok { 
    match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}" } 
  }
  date { 
    match => [ "time", "ISO8601"]
  }
```

With this data

```
[2014-06-19 16:07:02,347] INFO - [Start External Integration context]  [45] Starting service
```

It matches, but doesn't change the @timestamp.

What is wrong? I've spent a couple hours playing around with this and nothing I thought made it work.

Running windows if that matters...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it!

Looks like the date filter "ISO8601" is not working with a space between DATE and TIME

So this works

```
  grok { 
    match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}" } 
  }
  date { 
    match => [ "time", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
  }
```